# GCP: ADC + Impersonating Service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, identity-management

I am unable to authenticate properly using the following command

`gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<sa_email>`

The user I am authenticating with has the Service Account Token Creator role.

However, when executing this code, I receive the following error. I think I have done everything correctly. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

creds, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=<spreadsheet_id>, range=<range_name>).execute()
```

> \lib\site-packages\google\auth\impersonated_credentials.py", line 103, in _make_iam_token_request
> raise exceptions.RefreshError(_REFRESH_ERROR, response_body)
> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '')

Thank you very much for your help.

p.s. iamcredentials.googleapis.com is enabled.

Comment: Are you sure about the service account email? In addition, add scopes when you create your credential, you can't re-scope your token after creation in your code. You can find details in that article: https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-oauth-credential-going-deeper-the-hard-way-f403cf3edf9d

Comment: you can also refer to this [stock overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554732/gcp-impersonate-service-account-as-a-user).

Answer (score 0):

This is very useful [documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-oauth-credential-going-deeper-the-hard-way-f403cf3edf9d) @guillaume blaquiere
you can use this for reference.

Instead of trying to impersonate a service account from a user account, grant the user permission to create a service account OAuth access token.

Grant the user the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` on the service account. This role is called "Service Account Token Creator" in the web console.

Call the API `generateAccessToken` to create an access token from the service account.

[projects.serviceAccounts.generateAccessToken][1]

A simple HTTP POST request will return an access token. Modify the following request with the service account email address.

```
POST https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/SERVICE-ACCOUNT-NAME@PROJECTID.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "delegates": [],
  "scope": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
  ],
  "lifetime": "3600s"
enter code here
}
```

This API requires authorization. Include the user's OAuth access token in the HTTP Authorization header.

```
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Response Body:

```
{
   "accessToken": "eyJ0eXAifeA...NiK8i",
   "expireTime": "2020-03-05T15:01:00.12345678Z"
}
```